# Alternative algorithm for depth first search

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

A problem involves a depth first search in a directed graph to find all the nodes that can be reached from a particular node. The solution given below is giving a wrong result on codechef. But I cannot find any test case for which this might produce a different result that the usual DFS algorithm would.

I know I can directly implement the correct algorithm to get the right result but I want to learn why my solution was incorrect so that I won't repeat it in future. Please help me identify whats wrong with this solution. The code is commented to explain my approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef long long int lli;
vector <lli> g[1000+5]; // the adjacency list 1 indexed
void dfs(lli j, lli i);

int main(){
    lli n, m, k, a, b;
    // n = number of nodes
    // m = number of relations
    // k = multiplication factor
    cin >> n >> m >> k;
    while(m--){
        // a,b means a is dependent upon b (directed graph)
        cin >> a >> b;
        g[a].push_back(b);
    }

    for(lli j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    for(lli i = 0; i < g[j].size(); i++){
        dfs(j, g[j][i]); // adds dependencies of g[j][i] 
                         // to adjacency list of j
    }

    // ans is the minimum no of nodes dependent on a particular node
    lli ans = g[1].size();
    for(lli i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if(g[i].size() < ans)
        ans = g[i].size();
    }

    cout << (ans+1)*k <<"\n";
}

void dfs(lli j, lli i){
    // adding dependencies of a node to itself 
    // would result in an infinite loop?
    if(i != j){
        for(lli k = 0; k < g[i].size(); k++){
            // a node is not dependent on itself
            if(g[i][k]!=j && find(g[j].begin(), g[j].end(), g[i][k])==g[j].end()){
            g[j].push_back(g[i][k]);
            dfs(j, g[i][k]);
            }
        }       
    }
}`
```

The link for the problem : [problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CAG)

link for correct solution: [correct solution](http://ideone.com/zvehxA)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Agreed. This belongs on Code Review.

Comment: It only belongs on CodeReview if the code is actually *working correctly*.

Comment: do you get "wrong result" or "time limit exceeded" from the judge?

Comment: Please post the code with the **hard-coded** input into your program.  It gets tiring to see all of these "online judge" posts, and the code posted contains `cin` statements like this ( `cin >> n >> m >> k;`).  Just initialize n, m, and k to the values that reproduces the error.

Comment: When your search algorithm is modifying the structure it traverses, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @ead its written in the question - wrong result

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is the problem itself, I don't know for what input does it go wrong, just that it does.

Comment: @molbdnilo true there's a better approach that does not involve all this mess, but I think any additions to the structure occurring at an index greater than the current index should not cause a problem. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not aware of multi-edges which are possible with the given problem constrains, otherwise it looks correct. Take a look at this test case:

```
2 4 1
1 2
1 2
2 1
2 1
```

Your program will return 3, but there are only 2 vertices!

Having said that, I would like to add, that I disagree with the sample solution: It says the running time would be `O(N^2)` which is not true, because it starts `N` dfs every one with costs of `O(N+M)` thus resulting in `O(N*(N+M))` with `N=10^3` and `M=10^6` there is no change to be in the time limit of 0.01 seconds!

Actually, this problem can be solved in `O(N+M)` using algorithms for detecting strongly connected components.